# Bootstrap responsive gallery with match height for images

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Im trying and trying too build something i think simple but right know i dont know how to do it ;) Honestly i mad it few months ago but i lost files and i don have any idea how to build it right now

So, im using Bootstrap to build gallery i have 2 different sizes of images long and short ones
Long ones are 1920x1200, short 1200x1200px

im trying to build it in grid like

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="yourImg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="yourImg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="yourImg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="yourImg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="yourImg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="yourImg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="yourImg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="yourImg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="yourImg" />
      </div>
</div>
```

Of course it should look like in my preview img
[image: MY GALLERY GRID]

and of course img should be in the center of each column.

I tried to use JS for match heigh and it works fine but of course image is out of the parent div and i cant fix it. I cant use background-image beacuse JS is not reading the size of div.

Any ideas ? How to build it ? The best thing is that i build it ...... and right now i can build it again !

Thank you very very much !

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to match the containing div's size you should add this code to the CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

you can also save the original ratio by using this instead:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the structure of the html is wrong,
each row has 12 columns, you have put all the columns of each row into one row.

The code should be like this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <img>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <img>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <img>
    </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
       <img>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
       <img>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like this, the images should be organized more or less as you want